# TeamCity ChangeLog Details through API REST

Tags: api, rest, build, teamcity, changelog

I'm trying to get the changelog details through the REST API. So far, what I've got is this:
https://teamcity.blabla.com/httpAuth/app/rest/changes/buildType:(id:20140010), which lists the latest change in the latest build of the buildType. Do you guys know a way I can list N changelog details based on a build range?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Judging from the [documentation](http://confluence.jetbrains.com/display/TW/REST+API+Plugin#RESTAPIPlugin-BuildLocator), I think you are limited to a "since date" (start date) rather than a range. The query would look like this:

https://teamcity.blabla.com/httpAuth/app/rest/changes?buildType=id:20140010&sinceDate=20130305T170030+0400

where the date format is the same as that returned by the API.

Comment: I assume I can get the date from a specific build. so If the user enters the build. I can look for the build date and then use the sinceDate.

Comment: In that case, you can actually use `sinceBuild` then with the id of the build.

Comment: Glad to hear it. Good luck with your project!